# Typescript $inject $timeout into a directive ... works in controller, not in link

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript, angular-directive

**Stack:**
Typescript 1.7 + Angular 1.49

**Summary:**

I have a directive. I want to `$inject` angular's `$timeout` service. It works fine in the directive's controller function, but not in the link function. What am I missing?

**Questions:**

- What did I do wrong?
- Is there a better way to `$inject` the `$timeout` dependency?
- Why will the `$timeout` service work in the directive's controller but not the link?

**MyDirective.ts:**

```
module app.directives {

    export class MyDirective {
        priority = 0;
        restrict = 'E';
        templateUrl = 'template.html';
        scope = {
            'items': '='
        };
        controller = MyController;
        link = MyLink;

        static $inject = ['$timeout'];

        constructor(private  $timeout:ng.ITimeoutService) {
        }
    }

    function MyController($scope:ng.IScope, $timeout:ng.ITimeoutService) {
        console.log("controller", $timeout); // function timeout(fn,delay,invokeApply){ the guts here }
        $timeout(function () {
            console.log("This works fine");
        },3000);
    }

    function MyLink(scope:ng.IScope, element:ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attr:ng.IAttributes, $timeout:ng.ITimeoutService) {
        console.log("link to", $timeout); // MyController {}
        $timeout(function () {
            console.log("This throws the error, TypeError: $timeout is not a function");
        },3000);
    }
}
```

**Connecting it in  directives.ts:**

```
module app.directives {
    angular.module('app').directive('MyDirective',['$timeout',($timeout:ng.ITimeoutService) => new MyDirective($timeout) ]);
}
```

**app.ts**

```
module app {
    angular.module('app', []);
}
```

**What hasn't worked:**

- Using `this.$timeout` in MyLink, with or without including `$timeout` in the parameters.
- I've found several articles and examples that I've tried to make sure I'm following the logic of in my app but can't seem to get it.

**Final notes**

- Typescript-Angular is still new and there are so many best practices that are far from being defined. Part of my team's project is finding some of those.
- We have been working on this general structure for a while, so unless there's a compelling reason, please refrain from suggestions that I change the structure of everything too much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Link functions are not executed directly from directive instance, hence you wont get `this` as Directive's config instance (which you instantiate via `new` operator). Also you cannot inject anything to the link function (that is what directive constructor is for) unlike the controller constructor, the arguments to the link function are automatically passed in by the directive execution logic. You could use an arrow operator to resolve this issue.

Example:

```
 export class MyDirective {
    priority = 0;
    restrict = 'E';
    templateUrl = 'template.html';
    scope = {
        'items': '='
    };
    controller = MyController;

    link:ng.IDirectiveLinkFn = (scope:ng.IScope, element:ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attr:ng.IAttributes) => {

      //Here
      this.$timeout(function () {

      },3000);
    };

    constructor(private  $timeout:ng.ITimeoutService) {
    }
}
```

Or you could bind the context using function.bind. i.e `link = MyLink;` and access the `$timeout` using `this.$timeout`.

If interseted you could take a look at creating some syntactic sugars by using experimental decorators for directives or you could try exploring something [like this](https://github.com/mikeryan52/angular-decorators). However (just my opinion) using a class for directive config seems to be an overkill, you might as well just use a function with static inject.

Comment: Good one, better then mine.

Answer (score 1):

Link function 4th parameter is the controller instance him self.

If you want to do it you should do something like:

```
module app.directives {

    export class MyDirective {
        link = MyLink;

        static $inject = ['$timeout'];

        constructor(public $timeout:ng.ITimeoutService) {
        }
    }

    function MyLink(scope:ng.IScope, element:ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attr:ng.IAttributes, ctrl:any) {
        ctrl.$timeout(function () {
            console.log("This throws the error, TypeError: $timeout is not a function");
        },3000);
    }
}
```

I know that this is not elegant but I have hard time finding a better solution, what do you think?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, tho!